# How do I select multiple columns using Google Sheets =CHOOSE() function?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

From this table...

[image]

...the following formula in Excel...

```
=choose({1, 2}, E18:E23&" | "&F18:F23, G18:G23)
```

[image]

...gives me this

```
 {“UK | Primary”,555;”France | Primary”, 543;……}
```

[image]

However, in Google Sheets, it just gives me the first column. {1, 2} doesn't seem to work? How do I select two columns? The documentation for this function doesn't tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({E18:E23&" | "&F18:F23, G18:G23})
```

[image: 0]